# Rapid decay in kernel of first order elliptic operator

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-pde

Given an elliptic first order differential operator

$$ D\colon C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n, W) \to C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n, W)
$$

for some vector space $W$, can we say something about the functions in the kernel of the this operator? I've seen a claim that they "decay rapidly" for $r = \left|x\right| \to \infty$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. How could one show this?

**EDIT:**
Examples in the comment section show that this statement is wrong in the general setting. Is there a natural condition on the coefficients of $D$ that would make this statement correct? A reference would be fine.

Comment: Isn't the Cauchy-Riemann system a well understood counterexample? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: You cannot say too much Take for example the case $n=1$ and $D=\frac{d}{dx}-1$.Then $e^x$ is  in the  kernel.

Comment: maybe the word 'kernel' was meant in a different way?

Comment: Thank you for the counter examples. Is there a condition on the coefficients of $D$ that would make this statement true?

Comment: @Montecristo  This  remind  me an  statement  by  Nest  in  an expository  paper  on Atiyah  Singer  index theorem that The  CR  equation does  not  have  a decay  rapidly solution. Any way may you give  a  reference  to that  claim?